# Lombok alternatives for clear code without getters/setters/toString/constructors

Tags: java, lombok

Do you know any Lombok alternatives ? 
Using Lombok we can forget about messing classes with getters and setters and `toString`. I want to use it in my project, however I wonder if there are any better alternatives?

I am using Java 1.7 and cannot change to 1.8.

Comment: I don't think this question should get closed. While it's sort of asking for a tool, it's rather fundamental. It could be also rephrased as "is there a way to avoid writing all the common Java boilerplate", without mentioning any tool.

Comment: @maartinus +1 As often, closing is more made to strictly respect the rules instead of seeing users intention and interest… Why, if this is the only good resource I find when searching for Lombok alternative, this is closed? And what's definitely bad about opinionated answers (but it becomes some meta questionning): if you search for another thing than Lombok, it's that you've the opinion or the intuition that perhaps it's not the best way to deal with boilerplate code and you want the opinion of others on their found best way.

Comment: How about http://immutables.github.io ?

Answer (score 33):

I'm afraid, there's no alternative unless you want to switch to something like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org) or are happy with a smaller set of features like those provided by [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).

While `AutoValue` is probably the best you can get with pure Java, it offers

- @Getter
- @AllArgsConstructor
- @EqualsAndHashCode
- @ToString
- @Builder

but it misses

- @Wither
- toBuilder
- @Setter
- @Delegate
- @ExtensionMethod
- and some more features I don't use.

While I strongly agree that immutability is a virtue, it sometimes isn't applicable. Anyway, Lombok tries hard to support immutability, it even integrates with Guava's immutable collections, and you can write

```
@Builder @Getter public final class Sentence {
    private final boolean truthValue;
    @Singular private final ImmutableList<String> words;    
}
```

and use it like

```
Sentence s = Sentence.builder().truthValue(true)
    .word("Lombok").word("is").word("cool").build();
assertEquals(3, s.getWords().size());
```

Note: I'm not the author, so I can say it's cool.

For immutables, `@Wither` and `toBuilder` are pretty cool. The former allows you to create a copy differing by a single field and the latter gives you a builder starting with the current values and suitable for changing multiple fields. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
o.withA(1).withB(2)
o.toBuilder().a(1).b(2).build()
```

---

Both Lombok and `AutoValue` use some magic. The magic of the latter is the standard annotation processing, so it's pretty robust. It has some disadvantages as listed on [page 27](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE/edit#slide=id.g2a5e9c4a8_0134). I'd add the fact that some AutoValue_foo gets generated which I didn't order.

Lombok uses some black magic and thus is much more fragile, but it offers more and works pretty well.

Comment: "is probably the best you can get with pure Java" – with what Lombok does with with annotated classes it's at least controversial to still call lomboked code _pure_ Java.

Comment: @MichalM It's "impure" in the sense that it does things not covered by the JLS. You may call it "controversial" or "Java Plus", if you want, anyway it works well and provides badly missing and *only slowly introduced* features to Java. For example, with Java 10 we've got `var`, which is since long in Lombok. Lombok has also `val` ...

Comment: Completely agreed. It's just your original wording of "pure Java", which somewhat stood in contrast to "sth like Scala" in your answer that struck me. *One* of the reasons people *may* be reluctant to go with Scala or Kotlin or whatever may be ensuring source code compatibility across JVMs and their future updates. In this regard, thinking of Lombok as "pure Java" may provide a false sense of security – at the cost of all the other features one may find useful by switching to an alternative JVM language instead of just "Java Plus".

Comment: Of course there are other aspects, like the development or maintenance team familiarity with Java code. When considered at this level, Lombok code is hardly more than "pure Java" indeed. But it's just that, yet I guess the word "pure" awoke a kind purist within me – sorry!

Comment: worth noting that builder can also be accomplished with https://immutables.github.io

Answer (score 15):

"Better" is fairly contentious here, but one alternative is [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/README.md), available [here](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).  [This presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE) explains some of the differences between AutoValue and e.g. Lombok.

In particular, AutoValue emphasizes immutability (a good thing, generally!) and a minimum of extralinguistic magic (very different from Lombok).