# When working with immutable objects, how best do you return a copy with modified field(s)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, immutability, lombok

The Java 8 Streams API lends itself towards writing code functionally, rather than imperatively. As we know immutability offers many benefits and as such, I try to make objects immutable wherever practical. In day-to-day programming, I find myself in a situation where I'd like to "set" a value. My objects are immutable though, so I need to create a new object and initialise the field in the constructor.

I use project Lombok, which provides annotations such as `@Value` which essentially makes the object immutable. It also has `@Builder` which uses the builder pattern to provide a builder for the immutable object, setting fields unmentioned in the fluent API to `null`.

The `@Builder` annotation has a field named `toBuilder`, which, when set to true, provides the `toBuilder()` method, which returns a builder populated with the fields from the object, where the developer can "set" values, call `build()` and return a new object.

E.G. to create a `List` of immutable objects with modified `forename` fields, I'd do the following:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

public class SOExample {

    @Value
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    private static class Person {
        private final String forename;
        private final String surname;
        private final int age;
        private final int heightInCm;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(Person.builder()
                .forename("stack")
                .surname("overflow")
                .age(21)
                .heightInCm(180)
                .build());
        people.stream()
                .map(p -> p.toBuilder()
                        .forename("updatedForename")
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Without using Lombok, this would require a lot of boiler-plate code. In fact, I've looked at the generated code and it's neither small nor trivial. This leads me to question myself. How are others out there doing it? I worry I'm missing a trick.

Taking into consideration the description and example above, what is the best way of returning a copy of an immutable object with updated field(s) and how would it be used in the Streams API?

Comment: Just throwing it out there: if you want to start leaning more towards FP, but like working on the JVM, Clojure is great.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it the way the new Java 8 Time API does it, by adding `withXxx()` methods, e.g. [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#i60) has:

- `withYear(int year)` - Returns a copy of this `LocalDate` with the year altered.
- `withMonth(int month)` - Returns a copy of this `LocalDate` with the month-of-year altered.
- `withDayOfMonth(int dayOfMonth)` - Returns a copy of this `LocalDate` with the day-of-month altered.

Comment: Under the hood, conceptually it's doing the same thing as the builder.

Comment: @RobertBain Under the hood, it's not using a builder at all. It even has optimization to return object unchanged if the field value is the same. So they are only *conceptually* the same inasmuch as the *result* is the same, and that would only be entirely true if the builder could also return unchanged original object if no values were actually changed.

Comment: It's the future and `record` is here; but I think the exact same thing applies - use `withX()` methods as you've shown.

Answer (score 4):

How often do you find you're having to do this?

If you're doing this *in place* of having modifiable classes, then perhaps it's a sign that really immutability doesn't make sense for your type.

If you're not doing it all that regularly, then just generating a new one with the accessors (and modifications to values) from the original doesn't seem too bad; nor does the `Builder` example you showed.

```
Person personA = ...

Person personB = new Person("updated", personA.getSurname(), personA.getAge(), ...);
```

Comment: This is the conclusion I'm coming to. I feel that the functional / immutable style that the Streams API pushes the programmer towards doesn't fit with the imperative style of the language. You need both. Yet, they made a design decision to call the only method you can make side-effects in `peek` to discourage mutation. (for concurrent streams, perhaps?) I suppose you just can't properly retro-fit functional paradigms into an imperative language.

Comment: You can always have some method `Person modifyPerson(Person given);`, and then use that as a method reference in your stream: `people.stream().map(this::modifyPerson)`, etc.  if your only requirement is to call it within a `Stream`.  (Modify is probably a poor choice of word when you're returning a new instance, but I couldn't quickly think of a better one.)

Comment: I disagree. Having immutable objects is nearly always good (and sometimes rather necessary like when exploring a game tree in parallel). It's just that sometimes the allocation cost is prohibitive and that it may get too verbose. But with Lombok `toBuilder` or `@Wither` it gets pretty concise and readable.

Comment: I'm not denying immutable objects are good (and I tend to use them whenever I deem appropriate). But this is a `Person` object. Surnames change, ages change, occupations change. Assuming you're interacting with a database, then an immutable view of it I'd be behind, but as an in-memory representation of a person, I'd want it to be mutable.

Comment: @Robert Bain: this has nothing to do with imperative vs functional programming style. In Java, it doesn’t matter whether you write `setFoo` for a mutable property or `withFoo` for an immutable property, there is no builtin automatism in either case.

Answer (score 3):

With Lombok, it's as simple as you wrote or even simpler:

```
@Wither
class Person {....}
```

and then

```
people.stream()
            .map(p -> p.withForename("updatedForename"))
```

There's no intermediate object unlike when using the Builder. It's also shorter and more readable. Only in case of many changed fields, `toBuilder` is more efficient.

I guess, Lombok has no alternative here (in general, [AutoValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741964/581205) comes close).

Comment: I will like to add that `@Wither` was renamed to `@With`, and moved out of experimental and into the core package, in Lombok v1.18.10. You can read it here: https://projectlombok.org/features/With

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of helpful answers and comments which in their entirety have helped me reach a conclusion. I'm going to paraphrase / quote a number of these, with the aim of providing what I think is as complete an answer to the question as can be provided based on group discussion within this thread.

Andreas said:

> You could do it the way the new Java 8 Time API does it, by adding
>   withXxx() methods

I agree and from maaartinus's answer Lombok's `@Wither` annotation provides this. As he points out, when you need to change multiple fields there are potentially many unnecessary objects being created, so Lombok's `@Builder(toBuilder=true)` is more suitable.

Maaartinus said:

> Having immutable objects is nearly always good (and sometimes rather
>   necessary like when exploring a game tree in parallel). It's just that
>   sometimes the allocation cost is prohibitive and that it may get too
>   verbose. But with Lombok toBuilder or @Wither it gets pretty concise
>   and readable

I agree with this too. Immutable objects are nearly always good and this is how the Streams API was intended to be used.

If we look at how a more functional language such as Scala [addresses this problem](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-case-class-copy-method-example) it does something very similar to Lombok's `@Wither` and `@Builder(toBuilder=true)`, which makes me think the Lombok approach is good.

I asked:

> How are others out there doing it?

I think the "core Java" way would be to use copy constructors, or as Andreas suggests follow the approach used in E.G. `LocalDate`.

My personal conclusion is that the Streams API creates a requirement for developers to copy objects with changed fields but provides no assistance doing so. Without using a third-party extension such as Lombok things are more difficult than they need to be. Copying immutable objects with changed fields is the right thing to do, it would be great if core Java provided a simple way to do this.